# Unexpected token when loading ipython notebook extension

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install [execute_timings extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/execute_timings).

- I've copied the js and css to the nbextensions folder
- I've added the `on(..."app_initialized.NotebookApp"...` to the custom.js (on profile/static)
- I don't see any effect on the notebook
- I saw some other posts that were asking to check the dev console in the browser to look for errors.
- I see (in the console) the following:

`Uncaught SyntahxError .............. ExecuteTime.js?v=201506xxxx:4
Loaded extension: ExecuteTime ....... utils.js?v=201506xxxx:29`

Where xxxx are other digits.

I'm not sure what's going on as the multiple posts I see online make it seem like a straight forward process!

Edit1:
IPython 3.1.0 and using the master branch! I just tried the 3.x branch (and also 2.x for good measure).

Comment: I guess you are using IPython 3.x? Have you checked out the execute_timings extension from branch [3.x](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/3.x/usability/execute_time) or [master](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/usability/execute_time)? Comparing the commits, I'd suggest you will need the 3.x version.

Comment: IPython 3.1.0 and using the master branch! I just tried the 3.x branch (and also 2.x for good measure).

Answer (score 0):

The installation manual given on the linked wiki is slightly outdated. To use the *execute_timings* extension checkout or download the .js and .css file of the [3.x branch](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/3.x/usability/execute_time) into your nbextensions folder (e.g. .ipython/nbextensions).

Next add to your custom.js file the following lines

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp",
            function () {
            IPython.load_extensions('executeTime');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

This works fine on my machine with IPython 3.1 and Firefox.

I guess the problem you have is that:

- the wiki states `require(['/static/custom/executeTime.js'])` which is clearly not where you put the js File!
- the `$` in the app loader doesn't exist without additional definition (events, namespace)

Comment: I actually had it like that already. It was the one way to even see it loading in the console (I had found in another blog post). I was using chrome, but now tested in FF, with the same result!

Comment: Strange! I just checked on Win7 and Ubuntu and both work fine. Do you have the *Toggle timings* menu entry in the Cell menu?

Comment: No! Just the default jupyter items!

Comment: Ok, then you Jupyter doesn't find the extension. Can you give us the path to the executeTime.js file (with respect to the .ipython/nbextensions directory)?

Comment: It's in the root of .ipython/nbextensions

Following your comment I wondered if I should keep it inside a folder with the same name, but also didn't work!

Comment: After re-reading your question it seems that the js Files are found, but resulting in an error in the console, thus please try again the 3.x version (that is the one which should work - master is a bunch of commits behind 3.x!!!) and make sure that the old js is not cached. Use a different browser, incognito tab or something similar.

Comment: I commend and thank your resilience Jakob! I think I'll try it out on a fresh install as none of this seemed to work. I had already done most of the clean cache/incognito stuff before! I'll write back in a few weeks!

Comment: OK I finally figured this out. There is another folder which is not cleaned when cache is cleared in:

    user\AppData\Roaming\jupyter

What happend was that I had a bad file (I had saved the link for the js in github instead of the actual js file!) and that was always being loaded! This is a non-issue then, should I ask to delete this question?